# Change the way JRadioButtons displayed on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a `JPanel`, and I want to add `JRadioButtons` to it, this is the code I tried :

```
private void populateQuestionnaire(Question question){
            buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            for(Choix c : question.getListChoix()) {
                radioButton = new JRadioButton(c.getChoixLibelle());
                buttonGroup.add(radioButton);
                jPanel1.add(radioButton);

            }
            jPanel1.revalidate();   
            jPanel1.repaint();
    }
```

And I have the layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`.

This is how the `JRadioButtons` displayed :

[image]

I want `JRadioButtons` to be added one below the other and to be centered in the JPanel.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20938621/2587435). Its pretty much what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) is great for stacking elements on top of each other. Consider this code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton("My Button 1");
        JRadioButton b2 = new JRadioButton("My Button 2");
        bg.add(b1);
        bg.add(b2);

        BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        this.setLayout(bl);

        b1.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        b2.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        this.add(b1);
        this.add(b2);
    }

}
```

Which makes, when instantiated and shown, the following window:

[image: Screenshot]

Now let's look at how this code works:

Consider this code:

```
ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton("My Button 1");
JRadioButton b2 = new JRadioButton("My Button 2");
bg.add(b1);
bg.add(b2);
```

This code does the same thing you were doing before, only a little simpler for example's sake. It creates a button group and two `JRadioButton`s, then adds the buttons to the button group. Now here is when it gets interesting.

Next, consider this code:

```
BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
this.setLayout(bl);
```

The first line creates a new `BoxLayout` with the following parameters:

1 The container which it is laying out. (It needs this because it can't be shared.)

2 The axis which it should be laying out components. (You want Y-AXIS for your case.)

The second line set's the JFrame's contentPane's layout to the `BoxLayout` you just created.

Finally, consider this code:

```
b1.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
b2.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

this.add(b1);
this.add(b2);
```

This sets the alignment of the two radio buttons so that their centers will be aligned to each other and to the center of the frame. Then it adds them to the frame's content pane.

Hope this helped!

**Note:** The reason I used `this.getContentPane()` while constructing the `BoxLayout` instead of just using `this` is because when working with JFrames commands like `add()` and `setLayout()` get redirected to the frame's content pane. So if we were to use `this` in the constructor, when we called `this.setLayout(bl)` we really would be calling `this.getContentPane().setLayout(bl)`. But, we just told the `BoxLayout` it'll be laying out the frame, not it's content pane, so you'll get an exception saying that the `BoxLayout` can't be shared. To correct the error, we just need to realise that we are actually working with the content pane through the frame's methods, and update the BoxLayout's constructor accordingly to let it know what it *really* is laying out.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `FlowLayout`, which lays out items left to right and wraps appropriately, you can use a [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), which allows you to specify laying out items either horizontally or vertically.

You can set the `LayoutManager` for your `JPanel` at construction:

```
JPanel jpanel1 = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(parentComponent, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```